# What is a good example of css dependent javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

For page load speed optimization, Google recommends to order of style and script should be CSS first and JavaScript second.
I understand how this is good practice.

However in the document, it said "If the JS code has no dependencies on the CSS files, you can move the CSS files before the JS files. If the JS code does depend on the CSS contained in an external file — for example, styles that are needed for output you are writing to the document in the JS code — this isn't possible."

I cannot come up with a concreate example for the latter.

What is a good example of this "styles that are needed for output you are writing to the document in the JS code"?

The document is [Here](http://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#PutStylesBeforeScripts)

EDIT: my intention is find out the case when JavaScript absolutely need to be placed before CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

Some simple example would be, if your JavaScript needs the dimensions of a specific HTML element styled by CSS.

In that case the CSS from the stylesheet should be applied to the element, before reading its dimensions via `getComputedStyle()`.

Examples here may be defining a sticky table header for a table of flexible width, where the width of the header is set accordingly to the width of the body, after the body is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose when you have something like this?

```
$("#someDiv").addClass("my_css_transition");
```

It is generally good practice to do all style changes in JavaScript via CSS with add/removeClass rather than setting style properties directly with JavaScript. This makes your JavaScript dependant on your CSS. CSS could, for instance, define transitions, like fadeIn or slideIn. If these need to fire on page load, you'll need to have the CSS loaded before the JavaScript adds the class.

---

Eventhough this is sound advice from Google, know that this is super advanced stuff. If you have a run-of-the-mill CMS or Wordpress site you don't have to worry about this. If you're Google, Yahoo or Facebook, then yea, you should worry about it.

Comment: In this case, CSS should be placed first. I'm looking for reason why JavaScript should be placed before CSS.

Comment: If your JavaScript does not depend CSS. Ie. the case when you do transitions in JavaScript directly without the use of classes of CSS defined transitions.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I know how it is good practice and I'm aware not too much worry about it. I just curious to know the case which Google stated for example NOT to place CSS first.